# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Freezing Randomly

Tags: 14.04, freeze

I have been using Ubuntu some few times on my computer. I installed it some weeks ago alongside windows 7 on a own hard drive. I installed the Nvidia drivers with this guide http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-nvidia-drivers-manually-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html and did everything in it. After that everything seemed fine and I can play kerbal space program nicely without any kinds of graphical problems. I'm also using dual-screen (2 screens). But when I do stuff like surfing on internet or playing music. or surfing on web at my 2nd screen and playing kerbal space program on the main screen ubuntu freeze many times. When that happends my mouse can move around but is stuck at the screen it was on when it froze. I can hear sounds from the game like it is still going. I can go back to the terminal screen. Only solution is restarting my computer. But why does this happens? It is really annoying because this is happening allot. I have also use system monitor while playing (even before a freeze) and the RAM is FAR from overloaded and the processor is working at like 10-40% when it is crashing.

Specs:
AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor 3.10 GHz
12 GB RAM
64 bit system (ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit)
Nvidia Gainward Geforce 550 Ti Graphics card

Comment: It is just a guess out of the blue, but might you graphics card get overloaded/overheated? I am not well knowledged in this topic and just stumbled over your question, so forgive me if this is a dumb suggestion. I just thought two idiots thinking about a problem is better than one ;D

Answer (score -1):

Switch to another tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then type

```
sudo killall cinnamon
```

Comment: Ubuntu uses Unity, not cinnamon.  This is just plain wrong.  Please use the [delete] button below your answer to revert the negative reputation points you now have...

Comment: I want a solution for the freezing. not another comment to stop it one time use. Want to find out why it is happening because restarting the game KSP is taking along time when loading. it is also destroying my playtime. and I don't think it is overheating or that stuff. I can actually do allot of multitasking on windows without any problems on performance. including watching websites, youtube etc. while gaming.